# How to push new element in map under case statement inside loop in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am writing clojure code where I am using case statement inside the loop and I want each data in a single map, below code I have written and what ever data I am getting in print statement I want all that in a single map

```
  (defn formatGa4DimensionFilters [stringData]
    (def abc {:orGroup {:expressions []}})
      (doseq [semiFormat (str/split stringData #";")]
        (if (str/includes? semiFormat ",")
          (do (doseq [commaFormat (str/split semiFormat #",")]
                (def filterSymbol (get-symbol-for-filter commaFormat))
              (case filterSymbol
                "=~" (let [[key value] (str/split commaFormat #"=~")]
                       (println {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType "PARTIAL_REGEXP"}}}))
                "!~" (let [[key value] (str/split commaFormat #"!~")]
                       (println {:notExpression {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType "PARTIAL_REGEXP"}}}}))
                "=@" (let [[key value] (str/split commaFormat #"=@")]
                       (println {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType "CONTAINS"}}}))
                "!@" (let [[key value] (str/split commaFormat #"!@")]
                       (println {:notExpression {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType "CONTAINS"}}}}))
                "==" (let [[key value] (str/split commaFormat #"==")]
                       (println {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType "EXACT"}}}))
                "!=" (let [[key value] (str/split commaFormat #"!=")]
                       (println {:notExpression {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType "EXACT"}}}}))
                (println "x is not defined"))))
          (do (def symbolFilter2 (get-symbol-for-filter semiFormat))
              (case symbolFilter2
                "=~" (let [[key value] (str/split semiFormat #"=~")]
                       (println {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType "PARTIAL_REGEXP"}}}))
                "!~" (let [[key value] (str/split semiFormat #"!~")]
                       (println {:notExpression {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType "PARTIAL_REGEXP"}}}}))
                "=@" (let [[key value] (str/split semiFormat #"=@")]
                       (println {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType "CONTAINS"}}}))
                "!@" (let [[key value] (str/split semiFormat #"!@")]
                       (println {:notExpression {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType "CONTAINS"}}}}))
                "==" (let [[key value] (str/split semiFormat #"==")]
                       (println {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType "EXACT"}}}))
                "!=" (let [[key value] (str/split semiFormat #"!=")]
                       (println {:notExpression {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType "EXACT"}}}}))
                (println "x is not defined"))))))

  (defn ga4DimensionFilters [semiFormat] 
    (for [commaFormat (str/split semiFormat #",")]
      (def filterSymbol (get-symbol-for-filter commaFormat))
      )
    filterSymbol
    )
  
(defn get-symbol-for-filter [string]
  (doseq [ga4-filter-symbols ["=~","!~","=@","!@","==","!="]]
    (def match-found (str/includes? string ga4-filter-symbols))
    (if (boolean match-found)
      (def filterMatch ga4-filter-symbols)))
  filterMatch) 

(def stringData "ga:city==San Jose,ga:city==Bengaluru;ga:country=~India;ga:country!~United States;ga:state==delhi,ga:state==goa")

(formatGa4DimensionFilters stringData)
```

current print data

```
{:filter {:fieldName ga:city, :stringFilter {:values San Jose, :matchType EXACT}}}
{:filter {:fieldName ga:city, :stringFilter {:values Bengaluru, :matchType EXACT}}}
{:filter {:fieldName ga:country, :stringFilter {:values India, :matchType PARTIAL_REGEXP}}}
{:notExpression {:filter {:fieldName ga:country, :stringFilter {:values United States, :matchType PARTIAL_REGEXP}}}}
{:filter {:fieldName ga:state, :stringFilter {:values delhi, :matchType EXACT}}}
{:filter {:fieldName ga:state, :stringFilter {:values goa, :matchType EXACT}}}
nil
```

expected output

```
{:andGroup
 {:expressions
  [{:orGroup {:expressions [{:filter {:fieldName "ga:city", :stringFilter {:values "San Jose", :matchType "EXACT"}}}
{:filter {:fieldName "ga:city", :stringFilter {:values "Bengaluru", :matchType "EXACT"}}}]}} 
   [{:filter {:fieldName "ga:country", :stringFilter {:values "India", :matchType "PARTIAL_REGEXP"}}}]
   [{:notExpression
     {:filter {:fieldName "ga:country", :stringFilter {:values "United States", :matchType "PARTIAL_REGEXP"}}}}]
   {:orGroup {:expressions [{:filter {:fieldName "ga:state", :stringFilter {:values "delhi", :matchType "EXACT"}}}
{:filter {:fieldName "ga:state", :stringFilter {:values "goa", :matchType "EXACT"}}}]}}
]}}
```

All should be in single map {:expressions ... }

Comment: I think you've already asked this question and were advised to use some parser. I also recall that previous expected result was different from the output you want now. So, just for clarification- what is the expected output (produced by `println`s) and what is the expected result (value returned by the function)?

Comment: What ever printing in case inside loop, I want to return all inside one map (mentioned expected output) from that function.

Comment: Don't use `def` inside other def:s.  Use `let` instead.

Comment: That expected output can't be also the expected result, because it's a hash-map with an odd number of forms. (Also, the type of some values is unclear, because `println` of strings and symbols is the same.) I propose `{:expressions [ ... ]}` and the usage of strings for values, is that ok? Also, is there a reason for two splitting characters (`,` and `;`), or do they have the same meaning? (I recall that in your previous question, `,` produced something like `"orGroup"` and so on- that could completely change the way of solving)

Comment: Yaa Martin `,` produced `"orGroup"`, I guess  `{:expressions [ ... ]}` will be okay

Comment: Well, if you want the result to contain some `"orGroup"` or `"andGroup"`, you should edit your question (expected result) accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
(def match-map {"==" "EXACT"
                "=~" "PARTIAL_REGEXP"
                "=@" "CONTAINS"})

(defn parse-entry [s]
  (let [[_ label op name'] (re-matches #"(.*)(==|=~|=@)(.*)" s)]
    {:filter {:fieldName    label
               :stringFilter {:values     name'
                               :matchType (match-map op)}}}))

(defn parse-str [s]
  (condp #(str/includes? %2 %1) s
    ";" {:andGroup {:expressions (->> (str/split s #";")
                                      (mapv parse-str)
                                      (mapv #(if (= (key (first %)) :orGroup) % [%])))}}
    "," {:orGroup {:expressions (mapv parse-str (str/split s #","))}}
    "!" {:notExpression (parse-entry (str/replace s #"!" "="))}
    (parse-entry s)))
```

Example call:

```
(parse-str "ga:city==San Jose,ga:city==Bengaluru;ga:country=~India;ga:country!~United States;ga:state==delhi,ga:state==goa")
=>
{:andGroup {:expressions [{:orGroup {:expressions [{:filter {:fieldName "ga:city",
                                                             :stringFilter {:values "San Jose", :matchType "EXACT"}}}
                                                   {:filter {:fieldName "ga:city",
                                                             :stringFilter {:values "Bengaluru", :matchType "EXACT"}}}]}}
                          [{:filter {:fieldName "ga:country",
                                     :stringFilter {:values "India", :matchType "PARTIAL_REGEXP"}}}]
                          [{:notExpression {:filter {:fieldName "ga:country",
                                                     :stringFilter {:values "United States",
                                                                    :matchType "PARTIAL_REGEXP"}}}}]
                          {:orGroup {:expressions [{:filter {:fieldName "ga:state",
                                                             :stringFilter {:values "delhi", :matchType "EXACT"}}}
                                                   {:filter {:fieldName "ga:state",
                                                             :stringFilter {:values "goa", :matchType "EXACT"}}}]}}]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Let vs def

The overuse of def is the most glaring no-no in the code.  Every use of it above is wrong.

## regex is your friend

Notice that your function:

```
(defn get-symbol-for-filter [string]
  (doseq [ga4-filter-symbols ["=~","!~","=@","!@","==","!="]]
    (def match-found (str/includes? string ga4-filter-symbols))
    (if (boolean match-found)
      (def filterMatch ga4-filter-symbols)))
  filterMatch)
```

can be replace with:

```
(defn get-symbol-for-filter [string] 
  (re-find  #"=~|!=|=@|!@|==|!=" string))
```

## Without println

I'm not sure I understand the intent of the prinln (output or debug/dev?) and what the difference between ";" and "," separators (asked in a comment above) but a solution that you may be able to work from could be:

```
(defn get-filters [string-data]
  (let [match-type->name  {"==" "EXACT"
                           "=~" "PARTIAL_REGEXP"
                           "=@" "CONTAINS"
                           "!=" "EXACT"
                           "!~" "PARTIAL_REGEX"
                           "!@" "CONTAINS"}
        notExpression? #(str/starts-with? % "!")
        ;; note this regex is (re-pattern (str "^(.*)(" (str/join "|" (keys matches)) ")(.*)$"))
        re-key-type-value #"^(.*)(==|=~|=@|!=|!~|!@)(.*)$"]
    (->> 
     (for [sub-str (str/split string-data #";|,")]
       (if-let [[_ key match-type value] (re-matches re-key-type-value sub-str)]
         (let [filter {:filter {:fieldName key :stringFilter {:values value :matchType (match-type->name match-type)}}}]
           (if (notExpression? match-type)
             {:notExpression filter}
             filter))
         (str "No Match for: " sub-str)))
     (vec)
     (assoc {} :expressions))))
```

see that the "re-matches" line performs multiple tasks (i.e. finding the match and separating out the key and vale which you had done separably before)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
(ns match.type
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(def match-type {"=~" "PARTIAL_REGEXP"
                 "!~" "PARTIAL_REGEXP"
                 "=@" "CONTAINS"
                 "!@" "CONTAINS"
                 "==" "EXACT"
                 "!=" "EXACT"})

(defn get-filter [s m]
  (let [r  (re-pattern (str/join "|" (keys m)))
        ss (re-find r s)]
    (when ss
      (let [[key value] (str/split s (re-pattern ss))]
        {:fieldName key
         :stringFilter {:values value
                        :matchType (m ss "UNKNOWN")}}))))

(defn format-ga4-dimension-filters [string-data m] 
  ;; m is the map match-type
  {:orGroup {:expressions
             (vec (mapcat #(if (str/includes? % ",")
                             (mapv get-filter (str/split % #",") m)
                             [(get-filter % m)])
                          (str/split string-data #";")))}})
```

I use here the mapping `match-type` in its fullest.

Instead of writing everywhere `(println ...)` it is better to just return the value. And at the very end put the `(println ...)` around the call.

Or simply to collect the results. (separate side effects from the actual calculations).

Once defined a map, one can use this map also as a getter function. So one saves to define a function - one can even give a third value as its default return value - in our case "UNKNOWN".

`swap!` is a very imperative way - sometimes it would save time and memory. But here, it is superfluous. We could directly construct the result map. No need for `swap!` with `update-in`.

So I use a `let` expression instead and construct at the end `{:orGroup {:expressions exps}}`.

And one can use `mapcat` when collecting using a function which can return various numbers of elements which are to be collecte. So no need for imperative functions here.

Here, the match-type map is given explicitely into the functions.
(Referential-transparency). These functions are easier to test.

And personally, I find `camelCase` not very clojure-ish.

Try:

```
(defn get-filter [s m]
  (let [r  (re-pattern (str/join "|" (keys m)))
        ss (re-find r s)]
    (when ss
      (let [[key value] (str/split s (re-pattern ss))]
        {:key key
         :value value
         :type (m ss "UNKNOWN")}))))

(defn format-ga4-dimension-filters [string-data m] ;; m match-type
  {:or (vec (mapcat #(if (str/includes? % ",")
                       (mapv get-filter (str/split % #",") m)
                       [(get-filter % m)])
                    (str/split string-data #";")))})
```

I would flatten the filter simply as `:key`, `:value`, `:type`.

Just an `:or` as sign that the filters have the logical relationship `or`. That they are filters is clear - so actually no need for a `{:filters ...}`.

Comment: thanks Gwang for the help, I want {:orGroup {:expressions ..} on `,` separation. I have updated the final output in question
during execution of this code i was getting error
`; Execution error (ArityException) at user/format-ga4-dimension-filters$fn (REPL:83).
; Wrong number of args (1) passed to: user/get-filter`
on line no 83 `(mapv get-filter))`

Comment: @DeepakKishore There was also some logical mistakes - corrected them.